# URL rewriting on shared hosting, hide default.aspx

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting

I am hosting my C# 4.0 (II7) on GoDaddy shared plan, so I can't install any URL rewriting software. How do I hide `default.aspx`, but leave query parameters? Instead of `www.mysite.com/Default.aspx?p=1`  I want to have `www.mysite.com/p=1`.

Is it possible within web.config? How?

Answer (score 1):

"www.mysite.com/?p=1" (with the '?' before 'p') should be equivalent to "www.mysite.com/default.aspx?p=1".  This should already work.

(Incidentally, www.mysite.com/p=1 is not a legal URL; it would have to be encoded as "www.mysite.com/p%3D1".  To pass arbitrary paths to ASP .NET, you would also need to configure IIS to change the default handler (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx), for instance) in addition to web.config.)

Comment: So my question, if I have href="Default.aspx" , how should I hide default.aspx?? is there another way to redirect to homepage without pointing to default.aspx or using actual domain name?

Comment: If default.aspx is the default page, then www.mysite.com/?p=1 and www.mysite.com/default.aspx?p=1 should both refer to the same page.